# I want to use one dynamic row value as column name in mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql

First Table Name: Operators

```
operator_id  op_name 
   1          Demo 1
   2          Demo 2
   3          Demo 3
```

Second Table Name: Packs

```
 pack_id     pack_name    1      2    
 
 1           First     0.25   0.5   1.0
```

I want to Select * from Operators and if a first row of first table is selected and need to select value of which second tables column name equals to first table operator_id value in single my sql query

I have tried below but not working as excepted

```
$sql="SELECT *,
,(SELECT (SELECT operators.operator_id) FROM comission_packs  WHERE comission_packs.pack_id=1 ) as percent
FROM `operators` ";
```

I want result like below

```
operator_id  op_name     percent
   1          Demo 1      0.25
   2          Demo 2      0.50
   3          Demo 3      1.0
```

Comment: This is poor design. Dynamic information should be in contents, not table/column names. You can't use an expression for column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an expression for column names.

You can use a `CASE` expression to select the corresponding column from `commission_packs`

```
SELECT o.operator_id, o.op_name, 
    CASE o.operator_id
        WHEN 1 THEN p.1
        WHEN 2 THEN p.2
        WHEN 3 THEN p.3
    END AS percent
FROM operators AS o
CROSS JOIN comission_packs
WHERE p.pack_id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

a mpore dynamoc approach would be, but this would only wok for 1 comission_packs at a time

You should change your your design

```
pack_id     pack_name operator_id percentage
```

Which would make it easier to get your result or privot the querys to get all packs in one table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE operators (
>   `operator_id` INTEGER,
>   `op_name` VARCHAR(6)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO operators
>   (`operator_id`, `op_name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Demo 1'),
>   ('2', 'Demo 2'),
>   ('3', 'Demo 3');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE comission_packs (
>   `pack_id` INTEGER,
>   `pack_name` VARCHAR(5),
>   `1` FLOAT,
>   `2` FLOAT,
>   `3` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO comission_packs
>   (`pack_id`, `pack_name`, `1`, `2`, `3`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'First', '0.25', '0.5', '1.0');
> ```

> ```
> SET @fields = (
>     SELECT 
>         group_concat('WHEN ', `operator_id`, ' THEN  p.`',`operator_id`,'`' SEPARATOR " ")  
>     FROM
>         operators
>     ORDER BY `operator_id`
> );
>
> SET @stmt =  CONCAT('SELECT o.operator_id, o.op_name, 
>     CASE o.operator_id ',@fields,' END AS percent
> FROM operators AS o
> CROSS JOIN comission_packs p WHERE p.pack_id = 1');
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> operator_id | op_name | percent
> ----------: | :------ | ------:
>           1 | Demo 1  |    0.25
>           2 | Demo 2  |     0.5
>           3 | Demo 3  |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=354000957103cd5ea88f0607b9c92a13)*

Comment: Ya it's ok but we need to do this in php .. so needed in single query ?

Comment: No that is only possible with multiqurry https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php